# Creating an array to post in email body

Tags: arrays, vba, excel, loops, email

I am quite new to vba and was hoping I could get some help.
I need to create a code that generates an email that depends on the excel sheet.
Currently, I managed everything except for the following bit which I am stuck on.
The excel contains a list of options, lets call them a,b,c,d...n.
In the body of the email I would like it to say:

```
OPTION1 a
OPTION2 b
OPTION3 c
```

So I need the code to also work out the option number it is (the number of options can change, sometimes 8, sometime more) and add it next to the word option. I guess I would need to create some loop but really dont know how to proceed.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

This is code, with some sort of attempt at creating the loop. When i add the loop, my email returns a blank.

```
'Getting the xRg

 On Error Resume Next
    xAddress = ActiveWindow.RangeSelection.Address
    Set FirstRange = Range("A12")
    Set LastRange = FirstRange.End(xlDown)
    Set xRg = Range(FirstRange, LastRange).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
 If xRg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
 Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set xOutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set xMailOut = xOutApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
For I = 1 To xRg.Rows.Count
    For J = 1 To xRg.Columns.Count
        xEmailBody = xEmailBody & "  " & xRg.Cells(I, J).Value
    Next
    xEmailBody = xEmailBody & "<br/>"
Next
xEmailBody = vbLf & xEmailBody & "<br/>"

'Creating a loop for the legs
Dim a As integer
Dim option() As integer
For a = FirstRange To LastRange
    ReDim Preserve leg(a)
    option(a) = "leg" & a
```

Next a

this is edited code for the loop, but still not working...please help

```
Dim leg(0 To 15) As Range

Dim a As Range
For a = FirstRange To LastRange
   leg(a) = "Leg" & "[" & a & "]"
Next a
```

I get type mismatch

and this just returns nothing in the email:

```
Dim leg() As Variant
leg() = Range(FirstRange, LastRange).Value

Dim a As Variant
For a = FirstRange To LastRange
    leg(a) = "Leg" & "[" & a & "]"
Next a
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: done, added the code and my attempt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not very clear what exactly you are trying to do, so I am doing a little guesswork based on what can be inferred from your code.

Change this

```
Dim leg(0 To 15) As Range

Dim a As Range
For a = FirstRange To LastRange
   leg(a) = "Leg" & "[" & a & "]"
Next a
```

to something like this:

```
Dim leg(0 To 15) As String

Dim a As Long
For a = FirstRange.Row To LastRange.Row
   leg(a) = "Leg" & "[" & a & "]"
Next a
```

In order, the problems were:

1. `a` can't be `Range` datatype when you want to use it as a counter in a `For`-loop (unless you use `For Each`). `For a = ...` means `a` must be numerical, so `Integer` or `Long` in practice.
2. In the context of the above, VBA doesn't understand what you mean when you say "go numerically from the first range to the second range", as a `Range` object has many properties (the default one being `Value`, and not `Address` or `Row`).
3. You were trying to assign `String` values to a `Range` array. An array can only hold contain items with the same datatype as itself (except for `Variant` which can hold anything).

In your second attempt you are closer, but #2 from above applies there as well, Additionally, you didn't properly set a size for the array so it was impossible to populate it.

**An alternative solution** (though I am making assumptions based on what your dataset looks like, but I think maybe it's closer to what you will need):

```
Dim leg(0 To 15) As String
Dim a As Range, b As Long: b = 0

For Each a In xRg
   leg(b) = "Leg[" & a.Value & "]"
   b = b + 1
Next a
```

Translated to human language:

1. Look at each element (cell) denoted by `a`, in the range `xRg` (which your earlier code has defined as going from `FirstRange` to `LastRange`).
2. Add some text and the value contained in this element to the array `leg()`.
3. Once a value has been added to `leg()`, increment the counter that keeps track of what part of the array we're adding values to.

The code contains no errorchecking or array resizing, meaning you will get `out of range` or similar errors if `xRg` contains more than 16 cells.